# Checking if value exist in database in Django

Tags: python, django, validation

I have a category field `category_name` which is `unique` and I am validating the form value for that field after the form is submitted from django admin.

`admin.py` -

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class categoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

 list_display = ('category_name','module_name')

 def add_view(self, request, extra_content=None):
        self.form = CategoryUploadForm
        return super(categoryAdmin, self).add_view(request)

 def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_content=None):
        self.form = CategoryManageForm
        return super(categoryAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id)

 def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):

   if not change:
            category_name, module_names = \
                self.handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['category_file'])
   else:
            category_name = request.POST['category_name']
            module_names = request.POST['module_name']

   if category_name and Category.objects.filter(category_name=category_name).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('This category is already in the database. Please supply a different category.')
   return category_name
```

The error is--

```
ValidationError at /admin/accounts/category/add/
['This category is already in the database. Please supply a different category.']
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do this at all. If category_name needs to be unique, then set the `unique` attribute on the field in the model.

More generally, validation checks belong in the form or the model, not in the admin class.

Comment: The `unique=true` is set on the field in model.`category_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=True, default="", unique=True)` I just wanted to display an error message. I will try to validate it within form. Thank you.

Comment: The form will *already* do that if that unique attribute is set.

Comment: The form is not showing the error message. The form is uploading a xml file. After the file is being parsed, the category_name is returned to save_model.